# Filter array of strings against array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings like this

```
values[0]='1,3,16,5,12,43,13';
values[1]='7,1,3,16,5,23,49,26,13';
values[2]='13,1,3,16,5,23,49,26,12';
// etc.
```

on the other hand I have an array

```
filter[0]='13';
filter[1]='12';
filter[2]='3';`
```

I would like to find all instances of values where all my filter items are contained in the string (in this case `values[0]` and `values[2]` would match, `values[1]` wouldn't because 12 is missing). I've been trying for hours and I guess it's really easy but I just can't seem to find a solution.

jQuery is an option if it helps.

Comment: do you know the filters will also be a single value?

Comment: If you've been trying for hours, you must have some code to show.

Comment: Can you use [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)** to do that

```js
var values = ['1,3,16,5,12,43,13', '7,1,3,16,5,23,49,26,13', '13,1,3,16,5,23,49,26,12'],
  filter = [13, 12, 3];

var res = values.filter(function(v) { // filter array
  return filter.every(function(fil) { // checking all elements are in the string 
    return v.indexOf(fil) > -1;
  });
})

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

---

**UPDATE:**

There is chances to fail while using **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** . For eg: *`6` will match if string includes `16`*. So we can use **[`regexObj.test(str)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)** or **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** with word boundary regex for more precision.

```js
var values = ['1,3,16,5,12,43,13', '7,1,3,16,5,23,49,26,13', '13,1,3,16,5,23,49,26,12'],
  filter = [13, 12, 3];

var res = values.filter(function(v) { // filter array
  return filter.every(function(fil) { // checking all elements are in the string 
    return new RegExp('\\b' + fil + '\\b').test(v);
    // or return v.match(new RegExp('\\b' + fil + '\\b'));
  });
})

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Use `test` to check if string satisfies regex, `match` is used to extract strings.

Comment: a lot of good answers around here, in the end I used this solution. All my previous, own attempts were unfortunately not producing anything usable so I did'nt bother posting any of that gibberish :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter and reduce where the predicate is a regexp that checks that the value matches all of the values in the filter as a whole word.

```
var values = ['1,3,16,5,12,43,13', '7,1,3,16,5,23,49,26,13', '13,1,3,16,5,23,49,26,12'];
var filter = [13, 12, 3];
var filteredValues = values.filter(function(value){
  return filter.reduce(function(p,c){
    return p && new RegExp('\\b'+c+'\\b').test(value)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var values = [
  '1,3,16,5,12,43,13', 
  '7,1,3,16,5,23,49,26,13', 
  '13,1,3,16,5,23,49,26,12'
]
var filter = ['13', '12', '3']

var filteredValues = values.map(function(str) {
  return str.split(',')
}).filter(function(nums) {
  return filter.every(function(n) {
    return ~nums.indexOf(n)
  })
}).map(function(nums) {
  return nums.join(',')
})

console.log(filteredValues.join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing that:

```
var matches = values.filter(function(str) {
  return filter.every(function(item) {
    return str.split(',').indexOf(item) >= 0;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help :

```
function findMatchedValues() {
  var count;
  var output_array = [];

  $.each(values, function(v_index, v_val) {
    count = 0;

    $.each(filters, function(f_index, f_val) {
      if ($.inArray(f_val, v_val.split(",")) !== -1) {
        ++count;
      }
    });

    if (count === filters.length) {
      output_array.push(v_val);
    }

  });

  return output_array;    
}
```